# V8 does not clean up all garbage

Tags: javascript, v8, embedded-v8

I'm having trouble cleaning up garbage in V8. First, my Javascript is as follows:

```
var bigstring = "ASD";
for (var b = 0; b < 20; b++) {
    bigstring = bigstring + bigstring;
}
trace("bigstring " + bigstring.length);

function frame() {
    // generate some garbage
    var junkArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        junkArray.push(i + bigstring);
    }
}
```

From C++, I'm running a loop:

- Call `frame`.
- Collect garbage: `while(!V8::IdleNotification()) {};`

The expected result is that each iteration, the `junkArray` garbage is collected. After all, `IdleNotification` only returns true when "V8 has done as much cleanup as it will be able to do" [(doc)](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1V8.html#abcafb07ace99c980e42662299eb9eb1d).

In fact, the garbage is only cleaned up* approx. every 100 iterations. Am I missing a step? Is `junkArray` for some reason not garbage immediately after `frame`?

*Determined by comparing before-and-after heap usage

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `v8::V8::IdleNotification`, try using `v8::Isolate::LowMemoryNotification`. As far as I can tell that's the only way to get recent V8 builds to do a full GC via the public API.